# Running regressions in a loop for multiple dataframes in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have `16 dataframes`: `CGdf_2001, CGdf_2002 so on till CGdf_2016`. I want to run regressions on these dataframes in a loop. How can this be done?

1. `CGdf_2001` has colums `TSR_2001` and `sector profit`
2. `CGdf_2002` has columns `TSR_2002` and `sector profit`

and so on..

My regression formula is

```
TSR_2001 ~ sector profit, data = CGdf_2001
```

I want to run this formula for all dataframes at once in a loop

Answer (score 0):

> Note: is `python3` the example but you can remove the print statements
>   `'(' & ')'` and test it in `python2`.

Here is an example that accomplish your task, generated `dataframes` and than put them in a list, bellow is the code and results. In your case you will need to parametrize the formula if variables are different because you didn't provide sample of data I provided only the answer with variables/columns that has same name. `TSR_2001 ~ sector profit, data = CGdf_2001` for you it may be:

```
sm.ols(formula=df[x].iloc[:,0] ~ df[x].iloc[:,1] df[x].iloc[:,2], data=df[x]).fit()
```

> OR

```
sm.ols(formula=df[x].iloc[:,0] ~ df[x].iloc['sector'] df[x].iloc['profit'], data=df[x]).fit()
```

- `df[x].iloc[:,0]` # first column of data frame that probably is
- `TSR_2001` for `dataframe one` and `TSR_200n` for `dataframe n` etc.
- `df[x].iloc[:,1]` # second column `df[x].iloc[:,2]` # third column

> Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

#define dataframes, data for the model
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50], "B": [20, 30, 10, 40, 50], "C": [32, 234, 23, 23, 42523]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10, 3, 30, 40, 50], "B": [
                  20, 30, 10, 40, 50], "C": [32, 3, 23, 23, 42523]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10, 5, 30, 40, 50], "B": [
                  20, 5, 10, 40, 50], "C": [32, 5, 23, 23, 42523]})

# generate the list of dataframes
df = [df1, df2, df3]

#sores the results of the model
results = {}

#itterate and generate the putput for each model
for x in range(1, len(df)):
    results[x] = sm.ols(formula="A ~ B + C", data=df[x]).fit()
    print('Parameters for each reg model are:', results[x].params)
    print()
    print('The summary of regressionis:', results[x].summary())
```

> Out:
>
> ```
> Parameters for each reg model are: Intercept    14.991641
> B             0.229818
> C             0.000553
> dtype: float64
>
> The summary of regressionis:                             OLS Regression Results                            
> ==============================================================================
> Dep. Variable:                      A   R-squared:                       0.453
> Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                 -0.095
> Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                    0.8270
> Date:                Thu, 09 May 2019   Prob (F-statistic):              0.547
> Time:                        11:41:30   Log-Likelihood:                -19.963
> No. Observations:                   5   AIC:                             45.93
> Df Residuals:                       2   BIC:                             44.76
> Df Model:                           2                                         
> Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
> ==============================================================================
>                  coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Intercept     14.9916     25.386      0.591      0.615     -94.234     124.217
> B              0.2298      0.927      0.248      0.827      -3.760       4.219
> C              0.0006      0.001      0.717      0.548      -0.003       0.004
> ==============================================================================
> Omnibus:                          nan   Durbin-Watson:                   1.562
> Prob(Omnibus):                    nan   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.477
> Skew:                          -0.145   Prob(JB):                        0.788
> Kurtosis:                       1.515   Cond. No.                     5.21e+04
> ==============================================================================
>
> Warnings:
> [1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
> [2] The condition number is large, 5.21e+04. This might indicate that there are
> strong multicollinearity or other numerical problems.
> Parameters for each reg model are: Intercept    7.389442
> B            0.739083
> C            0.000133
> dtype: float64
>
> The summary of regressionis:                             OLS Regression Results                            
> ==============================================================================
> Dep. Variable:                      A   R-squared:                       0.712
> Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.424
> Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     2.473
> Date:                Thu, 09 May 2019   Prob (F-statistic):              0.288
> Time:                        11:41:30   Log-Likelihood:                -18.208
> No. Observations:                   5   AIC:                             42.42
> Df Residuals:                       2   BIC:                             41.24
> Df Model:                           2                                         
> Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
> ==============================================================================
>                  coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Intercept      7.3894     12.545      0.589      0.616     -46.589      61.368
> B              0.7391      0.545      1.357      0.308      -1.604       3.082
> C              0.0001      0.001      0.240      0.833      -0.002       0.003
> ==============================================================================
> Omnibus:                          nan   Durbin-Watson:                   1.522
> Prob(Omnibus):                    nan   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.285
> Skew:                           0.387   Prob(JB):                        0.867
> Kurtosis:                       2.122   Cond. No.                     3.66e+04
> ==============================================================================
> ```